# PowerShell write-host background color continuing past the code

Tags: powershell, colors, write-host, powershell-7.3

[image]

this is from VS code, also happens in PowerShell 7.3 in Windows Terminal

[image]

the code is this:

```
write-host "text text text" -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor white
```

that's just for a test, but it happens a lot more often when `write-host` is inside a big script and the background colors just keep dragging outside the text. how can I prevent this from happening? been having this problem for a couple of months.

p.s the correct word for this seems to be bleeding, so PowerShell `write-host` color bleeding is happening.

Comment: I don't know the answer but as a workaround you could use ANSI escape coloring, which is pretty easy to use through the global `$PSStyle` variable: `Write-Host "$($PSStyle.Foreground.Magenta)$($PSStyle.Background.White)text text text$($PSStyle.Reset)"` -- this explicitly resets the style which should avoid any "bleeding" into the command-line.

Comment: This doesnt happen in other editors, so I suspect it's more a vscode issue than a Powershell one.

Comment: I mean I don't know, did you even see the Windows Terminal screenshot in the post?
@zett42 thank you very much, yes that indeed stopped the bleeding, now no matter how fast I spam it, no bleeding occurs anywhere. want to add it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15130) related to scrolling. When the output of `Write-Host` involves scrolling, the background color leaks into the command-line:

```sh
1..100 | % { write-host "text text text" -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor white }
```

As a **workaround** you could use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for coloring, which is pretty easy as of PS 7.2+ by using the automatic [`$PSStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.3#psstyle) variable:

```sh
Write-Host "$($PSStyle.Foreground.Magenta)$($PSStyle.Background.White)text text text$($PSStyle.Reset)"
```

The `$($PSStyle.Reset)` explicitly resets the style at the end of the line which should avoid any background color leaking into the command-line.